# Release project with previous release version of a snapshot dependency on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I have seen some similar questions but didn't find any working solution. Now Its been a day finding to solve it. 
So, below is the problem.

I have a project which I want to maven release through a Jenkins job. But this project has a snapshot dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>market</artifactId>
    <version>121b4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is my project info:

```
    <groupId>com.domain.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>cash</artifactId>
    <name>Cash Flow</name>
    <version>123b4-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

When I try to release project manually with below commands:

```
mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

I got a prompt for resolving dependency snapshot version, So then I just input the previous released version of 'market'  - 121b3 and then everything worked fine.

But when I try to set up a Jenkins job to release the project, the problem is that how can I resolve the snapshot dependency on Jenkins (as we get the prompt when doing manually), as maven release plugin doesn't allow the dependencies with snapshot version.

Can somebody tell me

1. Whether It is feasible in Jenkins to replace the snapshot versions with previous release versions of dependency ?
2. If possible, How can we do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to release the project which contains the dependency first and afterwards you can release the other project which depends on it...

Comment: Is there any way through which we can automate this, because If I want to release project with the dependency previous released version ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not have any dependency with the word 'SNAPSHOT' in the version.

You will have to either

1) Release 123b4-SNAPSHOT so it is in the shared repository that Jenkins uses

2) Have an embedded repository (where you have a mini repository that is added to the project) and rename the 123b4-SNAPSHOT to 123b4, see [here](https://damienfremont.com/2016/01/08/maven-project-with-embedded-repository/) for an example

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>in-project</id>
      <name>In Project Repo</name>
      <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

I recommend option 1.